# Getting doctype error with jsonp

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jsonp

I am giving calls to limelight server with security parameters added at the end using ajax.

Limelight url suppose to return html (this is expected.)

now the issues is when I fired limelight url in Ajax it throws error -

```
SyntaxError: syntax error <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Now I can't avoid datatype: jsonp as it is needed in crossdomain call, and I can't avoid output as well it happens to be html5 source.

To Simplify -
1) limelight url - http://cdnllnw.xxxxx.com/somefolder/index.html?securityparameter = somehashvalue
2) above url returns html in fiddler and renders html in browser (when used in addressbar)
3) when above url is used in ajax -

```
$.ajax({
    url: lmlightLink,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain:true,
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    mimeType: "text/html",
    async:false,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.info(response);
    }
});
```

4) It throws following error -

```
SyntaxError: syntax error <!DOCTYPE html>
```

I had gone through multiple links in SO but none of them suggest perfect solution with jsonp and html5 response

Any Suggestions?

Restriction: Please note, I dont have control over response, so can't modify anything returned as html5 code from limelight.

### EDIT:

Please note I can't change the dataType = 'html' or anything else as it has to be 'jsonp' otherwise it will throw following error -

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
```

Comment: The problem is that your server response is `HTML` not `jsonp`

Comment: Change `dataType : 'jsonp'` to `dataType : 'html'`.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, When changed dateType, it throws another error-  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource, So can't change it